# Compensation for commercial use of photos

Tags: selling, licensing

I've been contacted by a multinational company for collaboration on decorating their new Prague office with some of my photos (https://www.flickr.com/photos/florin_dr/albums/72157634349951035).

My only experience with selling photos so far is limited to a few stock photography websites where the most I made was around $10/photo.

They want to print up to 80cm of width and use them one time only for decorating the walls. They have suggested various approaches to compensation:

- promote my work by having my name and photo description under each photo and at the reception area
- organize temporary exhibitions on their premises with more of my photos

While I feel flattered by these options, I also feel I should get a form of material compensation as they are a for-profit company and I'm not looking to go full time on photography (so not huge benefit from exposure in personal exhibitions, etc).

The question is what would be appropriate for a few dozen photos? 
I'd really appreciate an answer with some actual amounts/photo so I can at least get a ballpark figure in my head.

Thanks!

Comment: When you've gone to the dentist or doctor and admired the photographs on the walls, how often have you been inspired to go back and buy some artwork from that artist?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but perhaps pertinent: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21414/how-to-respond-to-requests-to-commercially-use-ones-photos-without-compensation/21421#21421

Answer (score 4):

Promotion in kind is valuable, if the promotion reaches your target market. So, in this case, will those viewing the images on the walls, or in the exhibits on premise, be potential future buyers of your photos?

I would guess not, and I would use this in your rationale back to them. Point out who purchases your images, such as advertising, publications, art directors and now interior design/building art curators. Unless this client is a building full of these buyers, you will receive no value from their in-kind offer. Ask for money and consult the local market for use of your images.

Answer (score 1):

Another user(cmason) has already covered the aspect of attribution well.

As far as pricing, I'm not going to give you a dollar figure because, it depends. What I can do is point you to a software solution that is widely accepted in the industry to be a good place to start with pricing when you aren't sure; fotoQuote - http://www.cradocfotosoftware.com/fotoQuote-Pro/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's answers.

In the end I've based my quote off microstock photo websites' asking price for print quality photos, which seems to be around $50 (at least on dreamstime.com).

I've then decreased that a bit as I suppose the local market is somewhat cheaper and asked them to donate the money to charity. I don't have a legal entity as a photographer so it would have been difficult for them to pay me for this anyway.

I don't make a living from photography and by doing this I feel that the compensation goes to a better use and also avoids any hassle with invoicing, etc.