# A Marketing Firm wants to buy non-exclusive rights for one of my photos, what should I charge?

Tags: legal, business, pricing, copyright

I was contacted by a marketing firm in Canada requesting that I give them a quote for non-exclusive rights to one of my photos.  The the firm does marketing for the company that makes exterior lighting tubing that was used to encase 3 miles worth of LED lights that surround a new hotel built in downtown Dallas (what the picture in question is of).  They state that they want to use the photo in print and electronic advertising, trade publications, brochures and publication inserts, websites, video and interactive media, trade show exhibits and support materials, presentations (internal and external), direct mail and e-mail, and other component groups as they arise.  They also state they are looking for non-exclusive rights and will not be obligated to include photo credit when publishing the image.  I guess my question would be how much should I ask for on my quote and how should I go about putting a quote together to submit to them.  Let me know if you need any additional information on this.  Here is a link to the picture they are inquiring about.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/wareagle8608/6391634405/in/photostream/lightbox/

Thanks for your time and help,
Kevin

Comment: If more than one separate company or individual discuss what they are going to charge or agree on what a "fair" price is, that's potentially going to run you afoul of price fixing accusations, which in the United States is a federal offense if it's determined price fixing has occurred.  If you match your price based on someone else's, that's just competition.  If you go find other people selling the same thing and discuss their pricing with them with a view to agreeing on a price (two ways), that could be price fixing.

Answer (score 9):

<strike>Here's the [rate card for Getty Images](http://www.gettyimages.com/Music/PumpAudio/RateCard).</strike> So sorry, scratch that. That's for music.

**Edit** I actually called Getty Images and talked to a representative and just ran the question by him. He said around $550 for royalty-free, non-exclusive rights to amateur work. But that's just Getty Images.

**Edit** I found [this article](http://photography.about.com/od/copyrightinformation/a/pricingyourphotos.htm) that has a few helpful tidbits. It mentioned [fotoQuote](http://www.cradocfotosoftware.com/fotoQuote-Pro/demo.html), a photo pricing calcuator. I'm downloading the demo now, hopefully it'll tell me something interesting.

**Edit** Demo isn't giving me much to work with. Not to mention that this application looks like garbage. But I suppose we can glean something from it... Selecting use for Brochure, 5k prints, full page ad, brings us to $750-$1000 already. Perhaps someone else on here can clue us in to conventional marketing strategies, how many times you should expect the picture to be printed, etc.

**Edit** If FotoQuote is actually widely used, perhaps someone here could run it through for you.

**Edit** It's incredible how difficult it is to find any straight answers. I found [another blog article](http://martybugs.net/blog/blog.cgi/other/makingmoney/HowMuchShouldYouCharge.html) on the subject, but of course it doesn't mention any hard figures. It links to a few photo price calculators, but they usually just make you choose a single medium, like *brochure*, instead of more broad advertising group like you are asking about. Probably most helpful, it links to this [Flickr thread](http://www.flickr.com/groups/procorner/discuss/72157594190929874/) that has a ton of resources. Hopefully something helpful there.

**Edit** I found this [photo.stackexchange post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7454/how-do-i-know-what-to-charge-for-licensing-an-image) that looked helpful.

**Edit** I think one thing to consider, your photo is not a stock photo. It's not like any picture of a building will do... they need a picture of a particular building. So that should add worth, more so than some stock photo from Getty Images.

Comment: Normally I don't like posts with lots of "**Edit**" notes in them but this one is kind of hilarious. Thanks for doing the research.

Comment: @mattdm Happy to entertain, gentlemen.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum $ woul be something like what Getty images charge. Their rates will be published.

Then there are many less prestigious stock image sites that also publish rates.

If this is a first or early sale for you the value of having made i so you can mention it elsewhere may be as great as any $ they would pay for it - so avoid pricing at  a level where they may seriously look elsewhere or take their own photo or commission someone to do so.

[istockphoto claim to be among the bigger sites](http://www.istockphoto.com/photo) and [here](http://www.istockphoto.com/)

[Dreamstime?](http://www.dreamstime.com/?gclid=CMqGr7r4jK8CFYmBpAodj2Gz_Q)